# postgres: how to store latex code within a text column

Tags: postgresql

i'm trying to put some Latex code in a PostgreSQL Database.
Created a table with cid as Serial type and code_text as text type.
After an INSERT Statement

```
INSERT INTO texcode (code_text) VALUES ('\document example');
```

i get an warning about false escape breaks within the Statement.

An

```
SELECT code_text from texcode;
```

returns me

```
"document example"
```

How can i fix this behavior? 
(i use an ruby script to Import my old tex files, so this above example is only to demonstrate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash by writing two backslashes, like this:

```
INSERT INTO texcode (code_text) VALUES ('\\document example');
```

Answer (score 2):

As it was said befoer you can escape the string  with doble slashes (\), if you get a warning you can avoid it using the E string, like E'\document example'